# Problemas al llamar una lista de mi servicio web Restful en java

Tags: java, webservice, restful, jdeveloper

les cuento. Estoy haciendo un servicio web restful en java con jDeveloper y el cliente alli mismo, tengo un metodo en mi servicio web que me permite listar la informacion de una tabla llamada Pacientes de mi base de datos .

```
    public static List<Paciente> listar(){
        
         List<Paciente> listaPacinte = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
            String sql = "select * from paciente";
          
            try {
                con = conectar.getConnection();
               
                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    Paciente p = new Paciente();
                    p.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                    p.setDocumento(rs.getString(2));
                    p.setNombre(rs.getString(3));
                    p.setCorreo(rs.getString(4));
                    p.setTelefono(rs.getString(5));
                    p.setGenero(rs.getString(6));
                    listaPacinte.add(p);
            
                    System.out.println(p.getNombre());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
            }
            
            return listaPacinte;
             
        }
```

En el servicio web lo tengo así

```
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("listar")
    public List<Paciente> listar(){
        
         return ServicioPaciente.listar();
             
        }
```

Para llamar el servidor simplemente uso la opción de jDeveloper de crear un Restful client and proxy y esto me genera todo lo necesario, en fin, el problema es que al llamar este método en mi cliente no me retorna una lista de tipo paciente, sino un objeto de tipo paciente.
El método que se genera automáticamente para invocar el servicio es este:

```
        public Paciente getAsPaciente() {
            UriBuilder localUriBuilder = _uriBuilder.clone();
            WebResource resource = _client.resource(localUriBuilder.buildFromMap(_templateAndMatrixParameterValues));
            com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.Builder resourceBuilder = resource.getRequestBuilder();
            resourceBuilder = resourceBuilder.accept("application/json");
            ClientResponse response;
            response = resourceBuilder.method("GET", ClientResponse.class);
            if (response.getStatus() >= 400) {
                throw new Localhost_AplicacionServidorHospitalRESTProyectoServidorHospitalRESTContextRootResources.WebApplicationExceptionMessage(Response.status(response.getClientResponseStatus()).build());
            }
            return response.getEntity(Paciente.class);
        }
```

```
public void listarPacientes() {
        modelo = (DefaultTableModel) guiListarP.jTablePacientes.getModel();


        List<Paciente> lista = clienteListar.getAsPaciente(); // Esto es lo que no se puede hacer 
        Paciente  paciente =  clienteListar.getAsPaciente(); // si lo declarara de esta forma no da error, pero entonces no sabría como poner la informacion en el jTable.

        Object[] object = new Object[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            object[0] = lista.get(i).getDocumento();
            object[1] = lista.get(i).getNombre();
            object[2] = lista.get(i).getCorreo();
            object[3] = lista.get(i).getTelefono();
            object[4] = lista.get(i).getGenero();
            modelo.addRow(object);
        }

        guiListarP.jTablePacientes.setModel(modelo);
       

    }
```

Necesito listar la información en un jTable, pero como no retorna una lista no se como podría hacerlo.Alguien tiene una idea de que podría hacer? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Y si el método getAsPaciente() fuera:

```
public List<Paciente> getAsPaciente(){
    //Retorna lista de pacientes.
}
```

Saludos

Comment: fue de lo primero que intente, si lo retorno en esta linea return response.getEntity(Paciente.class) y en vez de Paciente.class retorno una lista me sale un error, y si borro eso y simplemente le doy return list; al momento de ejecutar el método no se lista nada.

Comment: Yo retornaría un Json y al consumir el ws transformaría ese Json en una lista de pacientes con la librería Gson.